# how can you add a column on the anki homepage that displays information?

Tags: python, software-design, anki

Im looking at this https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/877182321
and im wondering how I can do the same if I wanted to create an add on that allows me to disply some extra information about each deck. How can I modify the homepage of anki to do this?

I could not find in the source code exactly how the add on does this.

Because what if you wanted to add it onto the LEFT side as well...